# jQuery fadeIn() not working with fadeOut()

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having a little issue with a jQuery fadeIn() function. Basically, what I have is one part of the screen that serves as the main display. I want to fade divs in and out of this area. Currently, what I have works for fading out the div that starts out there, but when I attempt to fade the other div in, nothing happens. Here is the code that I have so far.

```
$('#aboutbtn').click(function(e){    
    $('#slideshowContainer').fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $('#slideshowContainer').replace('<div id="about"></div>').fadeIn('slow');
        });
```

Like I said, this fades out the slideshowContainer div, but the about div does not come in it's place.

UPDATE --

Well, this is embarrassing, lol. I'm trying to reference a div that I already have in my HTML, so I guess that really the replaceWith('') makes no sense.

If I wanted to replace with a div I already have defined in my HTML document, shouldn't this work?

```
$('#aboutbtn').click(function(e){    
$('#slideshowContainer').fadeOut('fast', function(){
    $('#slideshowContainer').replace('#about').fadeIn('slow');
    });
```

The id of the div that I want to replace the faded out div is about. When I do this, however, it just displays #about.

Comment: What this `.replace('<div id="about"></div>')` supposed to do?

Comment: He probably mean replaceWith()?

Comment: My intent for it is to place it in the spot that the div that was faded out was in. Is this incorrect? FWIW, I tried it with a replaceWith() also, but still no luck.

Comment: Can you post a complete example with the HTML? A jsFiddle would be good too.

Comment: Have you tried putting a value inside the about div? Or is that from somewhere else in your html?

Comment: I've updated my original post with more info

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ujWQW/

Comment: Essentially the same as mine ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery object doesn't have `replace` method, use `replaceWith`:

```
$('#slideshowContainer').fadeOut('fast', function() {
    $(this).replaceWith(function() {
        return $('<div id="about">about</div>').hide().fadeIn();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ypgwL/

Update:

```
$('#slideshowContainer').fadeOut('fast', function () {
    var $d = $('#about');
    $(this).replaceWith($d);
    $d.fadeIn();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ujWQW/

Answer (score 2):

try to put text inside ur div

[here's my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/srF34/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#aboutbtn').click(function (e) {
    $('#slideshowContainer').fadeOut('fast', function () {
        $('#slideshowContainer').replaceWith('<div id="about">You miss this thing!     </div>').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example of what I think you are trying to do:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#aboutbtn').click(function(e){    
       $('#slideshowContainer').fadeOut('fast', function(){
          ele = $('<div id="about" style="display:none"></div>').fadeIn('slow');
          $('#slideshowContainer').replaceWith(ele)
       });
   });
});
</script>

<div id="slideshowContainer"></div>

<input type="button" name="button" value="Button" id="aboutbtn">
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do and makes sense, thank you. However, I added a little more to my original post. What if I already have the div defined in the HTML and don't need to declare it in the function as you have here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('#aboutbtn').click(function(e){    
 $('#slideshowContainer').fadeOut('fast', function(){
$(this).replaceWith('#about').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Or you could use AppendTo instead of rplacewith

```
$('#aboutbtn').click(function(e){    
 $('#slideshowContainer').fadeOut('fast', function(){
$(this).appendTo('#about').fadeIn('slow');
});
```